# Highcharts - How to add background in bar series? And how to print page without lose quality?

Tags: charts, highcharts, printing, background, series

I need your help, i try use "pattern" in Highcharts to use background in bars, but the images don't fill the space that i wanna.

[Bar Chart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtD9b.png)

I wanna know, how i do to leave the image with -90° than the way that is? And how i do to leave the image with height 100% and width 25%?

And beyond that i wanna of know, how i print the screen without lose the quality in image, because when i press "ctrl+p" i see all all blurred.

[Print blurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg0Td.png)

Follow below the current code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>HighCharts - Pattern Color</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" contetn="text/html;" charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://highcharts.github.io/pattern-fill/pattern-fill.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            backgroundColor: null
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Como você está?'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: ''
            }

        },
        legend: {
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'percent',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.percentage:.2f}%</b>',
                    //point.percentage:.1f
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Alegre',
            data: [30],
            color: {
                      pattern: 'http://emoticons.topfriends.biz/favicon.png',
                      width: '30',
                      height: '30'
                }
              // color: '#B22222'
        }, {
         name: 'Feliz',
            data: [30],
              color: {
                       pattern: 'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/58/30/09/240_F_158300957_MhRWEx1vDO6SPVHdGS4dqNG7nLP8rdZ4.jpg',
                       width: '30',
                       height: '30'
               }
                  // color: '#2E8B57'
        }]
    });
   });
  </script>

  
  <div id="container" style="min-width: 80%; height: 200px; max-width: 80%; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Since now i thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. PATTERN FILL ADJUSTMENT**

Refer to this **live working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/opa73k8L/

**Full code:**

```
var redrawEnabled = true,
    ctr = 0;

$('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        if (redrawEnabled) {
          redrawEnabled = false;
          var chart = this,
            renderer = chart.renderer;

          chart.series[0].points.forEach(function(p) {

            var widthRatio = p.shapeArgs.width / p.shapeArgs.height,
              id = 'pattern-' + p.index + '-' + ctr;

            var pattern = renderer.createElement('pattern').add(renderer.defs).attr({
              width: 1,
              height: widthRatio,
              id: id,
              patternContentUnits: 'objectBoundingBox'
            });

            renderer.image('http://emoticons.topfriends.biz/favicon.png', 0, 0, 1, widthRatio).attr({
            }).add(pattern);

            p.update({
              color: 'url(#' + id + ')'
            }, false);
          });

          ctr++;
          chart.redraw();
          redrawEnabled = true;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    data: [10, 29.9, 71.5]
  }]
});
```

In the `redraw` event I iterate all the points, create a separate pattern for every point based on its `width/height` ratio, apply pattern and redraw the chart.

On every redraw new set of patters are created which is not an elegant solution (old ones should be replaced instead). `ctr` variable is used to create unique name for each pattern.

`redrawEnabled` serves to prevent infinite recursive loop because `chart.redraw()` also calls the `render` event.

In my opinion the easiest way to have the rotated image is to simply provide the already rotated one.

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#createElement
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#image

---

**2. PRINTING ISSUE**

It seems to be a bug reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/pattern-fill/issues/20

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much for your help Kamil Kulig!